# percentage - px width in stylus

Tags: css, stylus

I'm having trouble with an operation using stylus. I thought I read somewhere that we can use calculations between percentage and pixels widths or heights, and stylus does the work to return the right value... However I can't manage to get it to work.
I did some research but didn't find anything related to stylus, I only saw some posts mentioning the function `calc()`

Here is what I tried: `max-width: (50% - 20px)`

This returns 30%! looks like it just subtracted 20 from 50! am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Stylus can't do it, also no other preprocessor. Stylus isn't able to know the real size of a percentage, no reads the HTML, only compile in to CSS. You should use CSS `calc()` function.

Comment: OK thank you, I gave up and did it differently :/

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for the native CSS calc it should look something like this:

```
max-width: calc(50% - 20px);
```

Note the white space on either side of the operand, it is currently required.

Comment: what about browser compatibilities?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/calc/embed/eras=-2, Unless you need to target old IE versions or some obscure mobile browsers you should be alright